# Adding an array of control in a reactive form in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```
 this.reactiveForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      EventType: new FormControl({value: this.EventTypes[0].Name}, [Validators.required]),
      StoreName: new FormControl('')
});
```

I want to have multiple `StoreName` as an array of formControl. I am new to angular. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: The documentation can guide you: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Comment: @JBNizet Again, I am asking about making the array of one single form control. Downvoting is easy, understanding is tough. As if I didn't knew there is a documentation. Thanks brother.

Comment: You're asking if anyone can guide you. The documentation can. Once you have read it, you need to **try** something. The example at step 2 of the documentation I linked to shows how to create a form array with a single control, which is exactly what you want to do. So that should really not be hard.

Comment: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/25/angular-8-dynamic-reactive-forms-example Go through this tutorial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [angular guide:](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays)

FormArray is an alternative to FormGroup for managing any number of unnamed controls. As with form group instances, you can dynamically insert and remove controls from form array instances, and the form array instance value and validation status is calculated from its child controls. However, you don't need to define a key for each control by name, so this is a great option if you don't know the number of child values in advance.

You can initialize a form array with any number of controls, from zero to many, by defining them in an array. Add an aliases property to the form group instance for your form to define the form array.

Use the FormBuilder.array() method to define the array, and the FormBuilder.control() method to populate the array with an initial control.

---

Example:

```
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

profileForm = this.fb.group({
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: [''],
  address: this.fb.group({
    street: [''],
    city: [''],
    state: [''],
    zip: ['']
  }),
  aliases: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.control('')
  ])
});
```

---

A getter provides easy access to the aliases in the form array instance compared to repeating the profileForm.get() method to get each instance. The form array instance represents an undefined number of controls in an array. It's convenient to access a control through a getter, and this approach is easy to repeat for additional controls.

```
get aliases() {
  return this.profileForm.get('aliases') as FormArray;
}
```

---

To attach the aliases from your form model, you must add it to the template. Similar to the formGroupName input provided by FormGroupNameDirective, formArrayName binds communication from the form array instance to the template with FormArrayNameDirective.

```
<div formArrayName="aliases">
  <h3>Aliases</h3> <button (click)="addAlias()">Add Alias</button>

  <div *ngFor="let address of aliases.controls; let i=index">
    <!-- The repeated alias template -->
    <label>
      Alias:
      <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use something like code bellow

```
StoreName: this.formBuilder.array([])
```

where you can pass initial values if you have in the empty array provided in the code above. I hope this.formBuilder has type of FormBuilder